# Writing a script that runs a command and times it

Tags: bash, time

I'm trying to write a script that will run and time a given and output that to a file in a `.csv` format.

So far from looking at SO previous posts, I've found that `sh -c "$index_of_command_arg"` can be used to invoke that command.

I'm also familiar with `time` and I know that people use `/usr/bin/time` for formatting, but I need to format the time given in `total seconds` (for example, `1.34516`) but the only given option to format the real time is `%E` which return `[hours:]minutes:seconds`. Is there any way to format it the way I need?

The general idea of my script is:

```
# ----
# some input validation
# ----
rule=$1
command=$2
execution_time=/usr/bin/time -f "%total_seconds" sh -c "$command" #is this line possible?
echo "$rule,$execution_time" > output_file.csv
```

Can this be formatted the way I want? and also, the line with the comment after it,
Will this even work the way I wrote it? is the syntax correct?

Comment: `%e     (Not in tcsh(1).)  Elapsed real time (in seconds).`

Comment: and how about the execution_time line? is it correct syntax?\

Comment: try `execution_time=$(/usr/bin...)`

Comment: Oh ok, got it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Say I use the normal time and I get the `real 0m2.003 ...`
>   output, how can I take the `2.003` out of it?

The *normal time* you are mentioning is the `bash` built-in `time`. From the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pipelines):

> The `TIMEFORMAT` variable may be set to a format string
>   that specifies how the timing information should be displayed.
>   …
>
> `%[p][l]R`
>
> The elapsed time in seconds.

So, you could use

```
execution_time=`TIMEFORMAT=%R bash -c "time $command" 2>&1 >/dev/tty`
```

Answer (score -1):

You replace:

```
 execution_time=/usr/bin/time -f "%total_seconds" sh -c "$command" `
```

with:

```
execution_time=`(time sh -c "$command > /dev/null 2>&1") 2>&1 | grep real |sed "s/.*m//;s/s.*//;"`
```

or with:

```
execution_time=`(time sh -c "$command > /dev/null 2>&1") 2>&1 | grep real | cut -c 8-12`
```

- Why `> /dev/null` - you don't want to see `$command` output 2>&1 (STDERR > STDOUT)
- Why 2>&1 for `time` command (for the same reason as in previous bullet)

Comment: the `%total_seconds` was just a stub, i was looking for something to replace it. so basically `/usr/bin/time -f "%e" sh -c "$command"`?

Comment: replace %total_seconds with %e

Comment: hey dude, apparently I don't have `/usr/bin/time` in my environment so I can't use `-f "%e"`. Say I use the normal time and I get the `real 0m2.003 ...` output, how can I take the `2.003` out of it?

Comment: `which time` returns nothing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97974/discussion-between-arseniy-and-giora-guttsait).